# Does "inquietude" make sense in this sentence?

Tags: meaning

Does "inquietude" make sense in this sentence?

Thus, the farmers had a great inquietude of the darkness.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As said, it doesn't work for a number of reasons. To get the same sense, try something like this:

> Thus, the farmers were greatly disquieted by the darkness.

Comment: Another, more common word might be "unsettled".

Answer (score -1):

No it doesn't, and "of the darkness" is the problem. Try "because of the darkness" instead.

Comment: What I'm trying to convey is Thus, the farmers had a great fear of the darkness

Comment: Without using the word "fear"

Comment: What about Thus, the farmers had a great foreboding of the darkness

Comment: Yeah foreboding works better, but it still reads differently.